# Python 3.7 MultiThreading strategy

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a work load that consist of a very slow query that returns a HUGE amount of data that has to be parsed and calculated, all that on a loop. Basically, it looks like this:

```
for x in lastTenYears
    myData = DownloadData(x)             # takes about   ~40-50 [sec]
    parsedData.append(ParseData(myData)) # takes another +30-60 [sec]
```

As I believe you have noticed, if I could run the data parsing on a thread, I could download the next batch of data while the parsing happens.

How can I achieve this parallelism of operations?

Ideally speaking, I would like to have 1 thread always downloading, and N threads doing the parsing. The download part is actually a query against a database, so it's not good to have a bunch o parallel of them...

**Details:**
The parsing of the data is a **heavily CPU bound**, and
 consists of raw math calculations and nothing else.

Using Python 3.7.4

Comment: I think it's different because `Ideally speaking, I would like to have 1 thread always downloading, and N threads doing the parsing. The download part is actually a query against a database, so it's not good to have a bunch o parallel of them...` this is not the "fire and forget" described on the question you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say if and how much this will actually help (as I have nothing to test...), but you might try a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). It handles all the dirty work for you and you can customize number of processes, chunk size etc.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(x):
    myData = DownloadData(x)
    return ParseData(myData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = None  # defaults to os.cpu_count()
    chunksize = 1

    with Pool(processes) as pool:
        parsedData = pool.map(worker, lastTenYears, chunksize)
```

Here for the example I use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) method, but according to your needs you might want to use `imap` or `map_async`.

Comment: As I understand, this will make both the download and data parsing happen on the same "thread" but, not the main thread, correct?

Comment: Correct, this is basically a parallel version of your `for` loop (meaning a few `x` will happen at the same time)

Comment: not exactly what im looking for. I don't want to cause a extreme load on the database...

Comment: @Leonardo I would say that ideal solution will be a thread downloading into some queue (as suggested in another answer), and a pool (as I suggested) reading this queue and dividing the work. I'm not sure how to do that sadly

Comment: With all due respect, your proposed **code goes straight against the O/P rules**. The first thing all pool-members will fire will overload the DB-engine, which was explicitly forbidden by the O/P above. So the `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` method is nice, is easy, but a tool for other use-cases.

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks for the grammer fix first of all. Second, you are most definetly right. I wasn't taking it in count at first and OP wasn't clear of that at the start (only edited the question and commented here after I posted). Would you say it is better to remove the answer?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Always welcome, Sir. No, I thing it is the Community practice to leave the interaction you have already had with the Leonardo in-place, as it helped him and can help others in future. **Stay tuned and positive - you did try to help and this is a great Community of Knowledge and you are a great Example of Active Community Member** - we all can learn and do learn every time here, so looking forward to our further growth, growing together, Tomerikoo

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a threadsafe queue. [Queue.FIFOQueue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html). At the top level define

```
my_queue = Queue.FIFOQueue()
parsedData = []
```

2) On the first thread, kick off the data loading

```
my_queue.put(DownloadData(x))
```

On the second thread

```
if not (my_queue.empty()):
    myData = my_queue.get()
    parsedData.append(ParseData(myData))
```

Comment: I like this approach, can you refine further on the thread spawning?

Comment: With all due respect, **you forget to mention the hidden costs** - you will pay the add-on SER/DES costs, that will be **AWFULLY GREAT** for moving the above stated HUGE-data "through" a Queue-(pickle-SER/DES)-mechanics + the thread-based gang-of-workers will all but wait for GIL-lock, before they, from time to time get a 1 / N - fraction of GIL-lock dictated freedom to process a bit of HUGE data.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is CPU bound you will have hard times to do anything else in other threads due to the GIL (global interpreter lock).

Here is a link to an article which might help you to understand the topic: https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil

Downloading the data in a sub-process is most likely the best approach.

Comment: With all due respect, you forget to pay the add-on process-instantiation costs, that will be needles to pay for having a full-copy process for just an I/O-bound receiver. The I/O-cases are the very ones to get easily latency-masked via thread-based split of processing.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *How can I achieve this **parallelism** of operations?*

The step number one is to realise, the above requested use-case is not a `[PARALLEL]` code-execution, but an un-ordered batch of resources-use policy limited execution of a strict sequence of pairs of :


**First**-a-`remote-[DB-Query]`<sup>(returning *(cit.)* **HUGE amount of data**)</sup>

**Next**-a-`local-[CPU-process]`<sub>( of *(cit.)* **HUGE amount of data** just returned here)</sub>

The latency of the first **could be** masked
<sub>( if it were permitted, **but it is not permitted** - due to a will not to overload the DB-host )</sub>,
the latency for the second **not**
<sub>( can start but a next I/O-bound DB-Query, yet only if not violating the rule of keeping the DB-machine but under a mild workload )</sub>.

> ***As I believe you have noticed***, if I could run the data parsing on a thread, I could download the next batch of data while the parsing happens.

It is **high time** to make thing clear and sound :

**Facts :**

**A** )
The CPU-bound tasks **will never run faster in whatever number `N` of threads** in python-GIL-lock controlled ecosystem<sub>( since ever and forever, as Guido ROSSUM has expressed )</sub>,
as the GIL-lock enforces a re-**`[SERIAL]`**-isation, so the more threads "work", the more threads actually wait for acquiring the GIL-lock, before they "get" it but for a **`1 / ( N + 1 )`**-th fraction of time of the resulting, thanks to the GIL-lock policing again pure-`[SERIAL]`, duration of **`N * ( 30 - 60 ) [sec]`**

**B** )
The I/O-bound task makes no sense to off-load into a full process-based, concurrent execution, as the full-copy of the python process ( in Windows also with duplicating the whole python interpreter state with all data, during the sub-process instantiation  ) makes no sense, as there are smarter techniques for I/O-bound processing ( where GIL-lock does not hurt so much.

**C** )
The whole concept of **`N-parsing : 1-querying` is principally wrong** - the maximum achievable goal is to mask the latency of the I/O-process ( where making sense ), yet here **each one and every query takes** those said **`~ 40-50 [sec]`** so no second pack-of-data to parse will ever be present here before running those said **`~ 40-50 [sec]`** next time, so
**no second worker will ever get anything to parse anytime before `T0 + ~ 80~100 [sec]`** - so one could dream a wish to have **N**-(unbound)-workers working ( yet have 'em but actually waiting for data ) is possible, but awfully anti-productive ( the worse for N-(GIL-MUTEX-ed)-"waiting"-agents ).

Comment: thank you for your post. I would just like to ask then why do people even care to implement lib such as CuPy if there is no possible gain because of GIL lock

Comment: Always welcome, Leonardo. Being Software Architect, you ought agree that a good understanding of tools helps to design meaningful use-cases & vice versa, a poor understanding of tools is prone to ill-defined solution approaches. If we agree on this, the GIL-lock is a python by-design property, not my invention, the less an opinion, it is The Fact. Understanding performance impacts the GIL-dancing introduces to python eco-systems is important. The Fact also explains why designers seek strategies how to escape from GIL-dancing, be it using an approach of  **[tag:distributed-computing]** or other